# How to make Win32 EDIT window on desktop outside of dialog take up all space

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to create an EDIT control directly on the desktop without being inside of a dialog box. I need the text box to take up all the available space in the window.

Currently I am trying to just do something like:
CreateWindow(L"EDIT", nullptr, WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 300, 50, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

But that results in a textbar that's almost as wide as my window, but not nearly as tall, surrounded by a transparent background.

I'm relatively new to win32 programming so any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just needed to add WS_POPUP in addition to WS_VISIBLE